# Order one list with a parameter from another list, with a joinable parameter

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have listA and listB.

ListA is a list of object which has an ListB object ID (foreignKey). And ListB is a list of object which has the property to OrderBy listA.

How can I order ListA by a ListB property with a simple Linq?

```
class OrderList
{
    public void OrderByDate(List<ProductionProgress> progressList, 
                            List<Production> productionList)
    {
        //Order progressList by productionList.ProductionDate
    }

    public class ProductionProgress
    {
        public int ProductionID { get; set; }
        public string Progress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Production
    {
        public int ID { get; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can join the lists with the join extension  method or the linq join  keyword.

Comment: please at least take the time to format your post so that it contains compileable code that can be copy pasted.

Comment: @MongZhu edited :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query:

```
listA = listA
    .OrderBy(a => listb.FirstOrDefault(b => b.ID == a.objectB_id)?.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
    .ToList();
```

This might not be the most efficient approach but it is safe. Because if you use `Join` it's possible that you get duplicate ObjectA instances if there are duplicate OBjectB(acc. to the ID).